# How can i specific domains for laravel multitenat system by laravel?

Tags: linux, laravel, apache

I need to specific a domain for each tenant in my laravel system
I am working with subdomains now and i need to `alias www.example.com` domain for `example.anything.com` subdomain .
that will be on apache config as i expect

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you may group your app routes by domain:

```php
Route::pattern('subdomain', '(dev.app|app)');
Route::pattern('domain', '(example.com|example.dev)');

Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function() {
     Route::get('/', function($subdomain) {
         echo $subdomain;
     });
});

Route::domain('{subdomain}.{domain}')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function($subdomain, $domain) {
         echo "$subdomain.$domain";
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but that will be on apache config as i expect

Comment: For your case, I would recommend using nginx. First, it faster than Apache. Second, it is more flexible with configuration, especially when you're working with multi-tenancy https://www.clickittech.com/saas/nginx-multi-tenant/